# Get the number of word occurrences in text

Tags: c#, string, linq

Can this be done using C# Linq?

For example:

> peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers, the peppers were sweet and sower for peter, peter thought

Result:

```
peter 3
peppers 2
picked 1
...
```

I can do it with a nested for loop, but was thinking there is a more concise, resource light way using Linq.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GroupBy:

```
string original = "peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers, the peppers were sweet and sower for peter, peter thought";

var words = original.Split(new[] {' ',','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var groups = words.GroupBy(w => w);

foreach(var item in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("Word {0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Count());
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = "peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers, the peppers were sweet and sower for peter, peter thought";
var counts = str
    .Split(' ', ',')
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Now the dictionary `counts` contains word-count pairs from your sentence. For example, `counts["peter"]` is 3.

Comment: You could use `Regex.Split(str, @"\W").GroupBy...` to simplify the word breaking. Contractions would be a bother, so maybe `[.,;:!?""\s-]` or something.

Comment: You're going to get counts for `string.Empty`, given this, as you have ", " sections in the original string...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Since OP says he can do it in a loop, I am nearly certain that he is looking for the part after the call of `Split(...)`. Thanks for mentioning the empty strings, though!

Answer (score 1):

```
"peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers,the peppers 
were sweet and sower for peter, peter thought"
.Split(' ', ',').Count(x=>x == "peter");
```

The is for "peter", the same repeat for others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's more efficient or "resource light", but you can do:

```
string[] words = "peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers, the peppers were sweet and sower for peter, peter thought".Split(" ");
int peter = words.Count(x=>x == "peter");
int peppers = words.Count(x=>x == "peppers");
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const string s = "peter piper picked a pack of pickled peppers, the peppers were sweet and sower for peter, peter thought";

var wordFrequency = 
        from word in s.Split(' ')
        group word by word
        into wordGrouping
        select new {wordGrouping.Key, Count = wordGrouping.Count()};
```